# Submitting operations in created future

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I have a Future lazy val that obtains some object and a function which submits operations in the Future.

```
class C {
  def printLn(s: String) = println(s)
}
lazy val futureC: Future[C] = Future{Thread.sleep(3000); new C()}
def func(s: String): Unit = {
    futureC.foreach{c => c.printLn(s)}
}
```

The problem is when Future is completed it executes operations in reverse order than they have been submited. So for example if I execute sequentialy

```
func("A")
func("B")
func("C")
```

I get after Future completion

```
scala> C
B
A
```

This order is important for me. Is there a way to preserve this order?

Of course I can use an actor who asks for future and stashing strings while future is not ready, but it seems redundant for me.

Comment: Order of execution would be random not just reverse. Returns `A C B` to me. It depends when the future is completed. If execution has to be sequential, why would you parallelise it.

Comment: @prayagupd just assume "futureC" returns Future (in fact it is actor ask result) and I don't want to block on first call in method "func".

Comment: @Igor, the point is, you are not blocking on the first call in `func`. It just happens to complete last.

Comment: @Dima, in this code I am not blocking. But if I want the right order of operations I must await future completion on first call.

Comment: You don't have to await completion of the first call.  
If you were starting all three futures in the same place, you could use `.flatMap`: `func("A).flatMap(_ => func("B")).flatMap(_ => func("C"))`. But, judging from your comment to the answer below, this isn't what you want. You can't coordinate between executions of different futures in unrelated pieces of code without some sort of shared state they'd use to communicate to each other. A global semaphore, perhaps, a queue, a single-threaded executor ... something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lazy val futureC: Future[C]
```

`lazy val`s in scala will be compiled in to the code which uses a synchronized block for thread safety.

Here when the `func(A)` is called, it will obtain the lock for the `lazy val` and that thread will go to sleep. 
Therefore `func(B)` & `func(C)` will blocked by the lock.

When those blocked threads are run, the order cannot be guaranteed.

If you do it like below, you'll have the order as you expect. This is because the `for` comprehension creates a `flatMap`, & `map` based chain that gets executed sequentially.

```
lazy val futureC: Future[C] = Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    new C()
  }

  def func(s: String) : Future[Unit] = {
    futureC.map { c => c.printLn(s) }
  }

  val x = for {
    _ <- func("A")
    _ <- func("B")
    _ <- func("C")
  } yield ()
```

The order preserves even without the `lazy` keyword. You can remove the `lazy` keyword unless it is really necessary.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Future.traverse` to ensure the order of execution.

Something like this.. Im not sure how your func has a reference to the correct futureC, so I moved it inside.

```
def func(s: String): Future[Unit] = {
    lazy val futureC = Future{Thread.sleep(3000); new C()}
    futureC.map{c => c.printLn(s)}
}

def traverse[A,B](xs: Seq[A])(fn: A => Future[B]): Future[Seq[B]] = 
    xs.foldLeft(Future(Seq[B]())) { (acc, item) =>
      acc.flatMap { accValue =>
        fn(item).map { itemValue =>
          accValue :+ itemValue
        }
      }
    }

traverse(Seq("A","B","C"))(func)
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't ready sequence of string, if I have no problem here. Somewhere in the program `func` invoked and it may be invoked again when the future has not completed yet. I thought about gathering strings and sending them to the Future when it will be complete, but how to accomplish this I don't understand.

Comment: `.traverse` does not guarantee sequence of execution, only that the futures in the resulting seq are in the same order (the completion may still be out of order).

Comment: Oh my mistake, thank you. Im used to a different implementation of traverse that doesnt do that. Ill update with an implementation that preserves that.